# How to depacketize the Mp4a-latm content frm the RTP packets?

Tags: aac, mp4a

How can we extract the raw AAC frames from an mp4a-latm content packetized in RTP packets?

I have gone through the RFCs 3016 but nothing is concrete and much clearer.

I have also seen the code of ffmpeg as how they do it. I have understood that they are using the config data and parsing it but how they are using it and what processing they are doing on raw data is not clear.

Can anybody help out?